# SSH to github.com only adds RSA keys - excludes ed25519 host keys

Tags: openssh, github, ssh-host-key

I am doing some tests around ssh. From what I have seen a server usually has multiple host keys. When a client tries to connect, it tries to negotiate which key types to use `DSA`, `RSA`, `ECDSA`, etc. But on key signature confirmation by the user, those host keys are added to `known_hosts`.

This brings up my problem:

I am sure I saw in `known_hosts` keys for github both for `RSA` and `ECDSA`(or `ed25519`). Now when I connect to github it only adds the `RSA` key. If I tweak the preferred algorithm with `HostKeyAlgorithms` and set it to `ed25519` only, it obviously refuses to connect with `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`.

I tested with a local openssh server and indeed it adds all the host keys. Why does github behave differently?

**Config file:**

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    HostKeyAlgorithms rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519
```

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has several different host keys: RSA, ECDSA, and Ed25519.  OpenSSH, when performing key rotation via `UpdateHostKeys`, will only accept keys that meet certain criteria, one of which is that they are not listed multiple times in the file.

Because older versions of OpenSSH used to store an IP address for host keys as well, this prevents those keys from being automatically updated in many cases.  That's why OpenSSH turned off the `CheckHostIP` setting in 8.5 and newer.  You can see what choices OpenSSH has made based on running `ssh -vvv git@github.com`.  Note that this decision is made by OpenSSH on the client side; the server always offers the keys, but the client decides whether to update them.

If it is the IP addresses, you can remove those entries from your `known_hosts` file and then the host key rotation should work.  However, this will be hard if you have a hashed `known_hosts` file, such as the default on Debian and Ubuntu.

If you don't specify any settings for `HostKeyAlgorithms`, OpenSSH will reorder the algorithms such that it prefers host key algorithms for which it already has host keys, so things just work.  However, if you specify specific algorithms, then it will override those defaults and always ask for them in the order you specified, even if that results in a failure to connect with the message you saw.